# picnet table filter not working with dynamic table

Tags: javascript

Hello I´m using Picnet table filter in two tables in the same page.
One of them is dynamically generated on my js file retrieving the data from MySQL database using AJAX. 
The other one has hard-coded data.

The one that is dynamically generated is the one that doesn't work. (I have created the hard-coded one just to see if the problem was related to that)
At the beginning I was also generating the "thead" and "th" tags in my js function but as I was getting an error saying that "thead" was undefined I moved that code to HTML file...currently I'm only adding "tr" and "td" to "tbody" by append function...but the filters are not working. For the one that is a combo-box filter the only option is "Select.." the other options that should be generated based on column data are not.

Do you have an idea of what could be the problem here? 
Thanks in advance... Monica

**HTML code:**

```
<table id="tablaReservas" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><th>Reserva#</th><th filter-type="ddl">Recurso</th><th>Inicio</th><th>Fin</th>th>Responsable</th><th>Usuario</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

Quick Find: <input type="text" id="quickfind"/><a id="cleanfilters" href="#">Clear Filters</a>

<table id='demotable'>
<thead>
<tr><th filter-type="ddl">Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Value 1</td><td>Value 2</td><td>Value 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Value 4</td><td>Value 6</td><td>Value 8</td></tr>
<tr><td>Value 5</td><td>Value 7</td><td>Value 9</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
$(document).ready(inicializar);

function inicializar(){     
traerReservas();    

var options = { additionalFilterTriggers: [$('#quickfind')], clearFiltersControls: [$('#cleanfilters')]};


$("#tablaReservas").tableFilter(options);
$("#demotable").tableFilter(options);         
}

function traerReservas(){
$.ajax({async:true,
url:"../Persistencia/procesaConsultaReservas.php",
type:"POST",
datatype:"json",
success:mostrarTabla,
error:mensajeTablaReservas, 
});
}

function mostrarTabla(data){
var d= eval('(' + data + ')');  

if (data!=0) {
for (i=0; i < d.length; i++) {      
var tr= $("<tr id='" + d[i].id + "' onclick=mostrarRecursos(" + d[i].id + ");>" +
"<td>" + d[i].id + "</td>" + 
"<td>" + d[i].nombre + "</td>" + 
"<td>" + d[i].inicio + "</td>" + 
"<td>" + d[i].fin + "</td>" + 
"<td>" + d[i].responsable + "</td>" + 
"<td>" + d[i].usuario + "</td>" + 
"</tr>");

$("#tablaReservas tbody").append(tr);   
}
}       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the PicNet table in the document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#m-stats-table').tableFilter();
});
```

Then, in the success callback of your ajax statement, refresh the filters:

```
$('#m-stats-table').tableFilterRefresh();
```

Also, make sure that when you are clearing the table before loading it, you are not removing the initial picnet filters.

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use the filters is by directly accessing the table column id. Although this approach may not be the right way to go about it, it works.

Each column of the table is identified as filter_0, filter_1 and so on. So pass the value that you want to filter directly to the column.

```
$('#filter_0').val('pass your value here');
```

This works on dynamically generated or hard coded table. However, if there are multiple tables in the same page you can use the .closest method to identify and modify your code accordingly.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a JSP page which connects to the server and fetches the data dynamically.

2) Load the JSP data in the table body and initialize the search plugin

```
$('#demotable tbody').load('fetchedData.jsp',function(){
  var options = { additionalFilterTriggers: [$('#quickfind')], clearFiltersControls:  [$('#cleanfilters')]};

  $("#demotable").tableFilter(options);
  //Define other functions for event trigger
});
```

This works for me!!!